# makepdf javascript problems

Tags: javascript, pdf

Hallo I'm not an js programmer but a frind asked me to write an litle form wich should produce an pdf document at the end. So I thought that could't be so dificult.
Finally I found the following [engine](https://bpampuch.github.io/pdfmake/index.html#/gettingstarted). But I'm unable to get it working. 
I incuded `pdfmake.min.js ;vfs_fonts.js ;jquery.min.js`.
Had anyone already used this engine? And was able to produce an pdf.
and tried this example code:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript?\" charset=\"utf-8\">

var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake' };
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open(test.pdf);

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to get this working? I tried exactly what you did and all I'm getting is a tab with the url "about:blank" and it closes itself automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, **test.pdf** is not in quotes. Try this,

```
<script>
    var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with   pdfMake' };
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open('test.pdf');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use minified version of the library, then it works…

Edit:
Sorry, use pdfmake.js

Comment: Hi, if you notice the OP mentions two minified libraries in his question. Could you please indicate which library whose non-minified version he ought to use?

Comment: pdfmake author here ;) minified version works fine now