# Cannot get pdfmake to work for me

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I am a complete novice when it comes to javascript. I want to use pdfmake so that i can save the output of my html page in a pdf. Below are the exact steps i followed.

1. Copied pdfmake.min.js and vfs_fonts.js to a directory called build. I got this code from https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake. I downloaded the zip file and copied the above files over.
2. Below is the code i am using:

> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html lang='en'>
> <head>
> <meta charset='utf-8'>
>
> <script src="build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
> <script src="build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" >
> var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake'     };
> pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open('test.pdf');
> </script>
> ```

What am I doing wrong here ? Will appreciate any help.

Original post : [makepdf javascript problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475971/makepdf-javascript-problems)
Browser tried: Firefox, chrome and safari

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src="build/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" >
var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with   pdfMake' };
alert("Will this work  ");
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open('test.pdf');
</script>

Comment: Looks fine actually, are you sure you dropped the javascript files in the correct localtion? Any errors when you hit F12 to popup devtools ?

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution and it worked in all the browsers. The link to the same in jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/krishnatcs1859/aey8Lhz7/3/.
Once you are in jsfiddle link, click on run. You should see the pdf downloaded to ur machine

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.68/pdfmake.min.js" integrity="sha512-gYUM+7JjtBqPPGOgwgOZ+NwjGl+11/EP124oB+ihjlBpLgP5LTh7R/Iwcdy//cgH+QzrjspBiJI5iUegTNww3w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <!-- Give the reference of your pdf content javascript file if any -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
     
     // var particpantName = document.getElementById('hdnParticipantName').value;
// var signedDate = document.getElementById('hdnSignedDate').value;
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

var usercertificateDD = {
    pageOrientation: 'landscape',
    pageSize: 'LETTER',
    background: [

        {
            svg: '<svg width="159.5" height="153.139" viewBox="0 0 159.5 153.139"><path id="Intersection_1" data-name="Intersection 1" d="M25.02,204.885C7.758,177.946-.408,146.962,4.329,114.5H30.037a113.537,113.537,0,0,0-1.254,14.457C27.34,182.2,65.469,229.82,117.239,240.224A108.481,108.481,0,0,0,162.5,240.1v25.533a125.194,125.194,0,0,1-22.293,2C97.434,267.64,55.014,245.781,25.02,204.885ZM58.573,190.9c-16.894-23.394-22.831-50.729-18.207-76.4H65.993a72.587,72.587,0,0,0,12.246,62.213C97.41,203.259,130.729,213.684,162.5,203v27.039a90.514,90.514,0,0,1-22.8,2.885C109.118,232.923,78.116,217.961,58.573,190.9Zm57.58-1.49c-11.47-3.816-19.754-11.839-27.522-20.873-5.828-9.795-11.141-20.6-11.153-32.681-.068-4.4-1.541-11.614,5.68-11.1,1.376.1,2.849.081,4.344.063,6.348-.074,13.081-.148,14.415,8.676,2.321,16.142,9.875,26.6,24.474,33.889,9.53,4.579,4.172,13.535,2.5,19.834-.875,3.579-2.715,4.713-4.882,4.713C121.5,191.935,118.548,190.413,116.153,189.409Z" transform="translate(-3 -114.5)" fill="rgba(241,241,241,0.53)"/></svg>',
            alignment: 'right',
            width: 250


        },
        {
            svg: '<svg width="159.5" height="153.139" viewBox="0 0 159.5 153.139"><path id="Intersection_1" data-name="Intersection 1" d="M25.02,204.885C7.758,177.946-.408,146.962,4.329,114.5H30.037a113.537,113.537,0,0,0-1.254,14.457C27.34,182.2,65.469,229.82,117.239,240.224A108.481,108.481,0,0,0,162.5,240.1v25.533a125.194,125.194,0,0,1-22.293,2C97.434,267.64,55.014,245.781,25.02,204.885ZM58.573,190.9c-16.894-23.394-22.831-50.729-18.207-76.4H65.993a72.587,72.587,0,0,0,12.246,62.213C97.41,203.259,130.729,213.684,162.5,203v27.039a90.514,90.514,0,0,1-22.8,2.885C109.118,232.923,78.116,217.961,58.573,190.9Zm57.58-1.49c-11.47-3.816-19.754-11.839-27.522-20.873-5.828-9.795-11.141-20.6-11.153-32.681-.068-4.4-1.541-11.614,5.68-11.1,1.376.1,2.849.081,4.344.063,6.348-.074,13.081-.148,14.415,8.676,2.321,16.142,9.875,26.6,24.474,33.889,9.53,4.579,4.172,13.535,2.5,19.834-.875,3.579-2.715,4.713-4.882,4.713C121.5,191.935,118.548,190.413,116.153,189.409Z" transform="translate(-3 -114.5)" fill="rgba(241,241,241,0.53)"/></svg>',
            alignment: 'left',
            margin: [20, -240, 20, 20],
        },
        {
           svg: '<svg width="159.5" height="153.139" viewBox="0 0 159.5 153.139"><path id="Intersection_1" data-name="Intersection 1" d="M25.02,204.885C7.758,177.946-.408,146.962,4.329,114.5H30.037a113.537,113.537,0,0,0-1.254,14.457C27.34,182.2,65.469,229.82,117.239,240.224A108.481,108.481,0,0,0,162.5,240.1v25.533a125.194,125.194,0,0,1-22.293,2C97.434,267.64,55.014,245.781,25.02,204.885ZM58.573,190.9c-16.894-23.394-22.831-50.729-18.207-76.4H65.993a72.587,72.587,0,0,0,12.246,62.213C97.41,203.259,130.729,213.684,162.5,203v27.039a90.514,90.514,0,0,1-22.8,2.885C109.118,232.923,78.116,217.961,58.573,190.9Zm57.58-1.49c-11.47-3.816-19.754-11.839-27.522-20.873-5.828-9.795-11.141-20.6-11.153-32.681-.068-4.4-1.541-11.614,5.68-11.1,1.376.1,2.849.081,4.344.063,6.348-.074,13.081-.148,14.415,8.676,2.321,16.142,9.875,26.6,24.474,33.889,9.53,4.579,4.172,13.535,2.5,19.834-.875,3.579-2.715,4.713-4.882,4.713C121.5,191.935,118.548,190.413,116.153,189.409Z" transform="translate(-3 -114.5)" fill="rgba(241,241,241,0.53)"/></svg>',
            alignment: 'left',
            margin: [20, 500, 20, 20],
            width: 150,

        },
        {
            svg: '<svg width="159.5" height="153.139" viewBox="0 0 159.5 153.139"><path id="Intersection_1" data-name="Intersection 1" d="M25.02,204.885C7.758,177.946-.408,146.962,4.329,114.5H30.037a113.537,113.537,0,0,0-1.254,14.457C27.34,182.2,65.469,229.82,117.239,240.224A108.481,108.481,0,0,0,162.5,240.1v25.533a125.194,125.194,0,0,1-22.293,2C97.434,267.64,55.014,245.781,25.02,204.885ZM58.573,190.9c-16.894-23.394-22.831-50.729-18.207-76.4H65.993a72.587,72.587,0,0,0,12.246,62.213C97.41,203.259,130.729,213.684,162.5,203v27.039a90.514,90.514,0,0,1-22.8,2.885C109.118,232.923,78.116,217.961,58.573,190.9Zm57.58-1.49c-11.47-3.816-19.754-11.839-27.522-20.873-5.828-9.795-11.141-20.6-11.153-32.681-.068-4.4-1.541-11.614,5.68-11.1,1.376.1,2.849.081,4.344.063,6.348-.074,13.081-.148,14.415,8.676,2.321,16.142,9.875,26.6,24.474,33.889,9.53,4.579,4.172,13.535,2.5,19.834-.875,3.579-2.715,4.713-4.882,4.713C121.5,191.935,118.548,190.413,116.153,189.409Z" transform="translate(-3 -114.5)" fill="rgba(241,241,241,0.53)"/></svg>',
            alignment: 'left',
            margin: [20, -15, 20, 20]

        }
    ],

    content: [
        {
            svg: '<svg width="159.5" height="153.139" viewBox="0 0 159.5 153.139"><path id="Intersection_1" data-name="Intersection 1" d="M25.02,204.885C7.758,177.946-.408,146.962,4.329,114.5H30.037a113.537,113.537,0,0,0-1.254,14.457C27.34,182.2,65.469,229.82,117.239,240.224A108.481,108.481,0,0,0,162.5,240.1v25.533a125.194,125.194,0,0,1-22.293,2C97.434,267.64,55.014,245.781,25.02,204.885ZM58.573,190.9c-16.894-23.394-22.831-50.729-18.207-76.4H65.993a72.587,72.587,0,0,0,12.246,62.213C97.41,203.259,130.729,213.684,162.5,203v27.039a90.514,90.514,0,0,1-22.8,2.885C109.118,232.923,78.116,217.961,58.573,190.9Zm57.58-1.49c-11.47-3.816-19.754-11.839-27.522-20.873-5.828-9.795-11.141-20.6-11.153-32.681-.068-4.4-1.541-11.614,5.68-11.1,1.376.1,2.849.081,4.344.063,6.348-.074,13.081-.148,14.415,8.676,2.321,16.142,9.875,26.6,24.474,33.889,9.53,4.579,4.172,13.535,2.5,19.834-.875,3.579-2.715,4.713-4.882,4.713C121.5,191.935,118.548,190.413,116.153,189.409Z" transform="translate(-3 -114.5)" fill="rgba(241,241,241,0.53)"/></svg>',
            alignment: 'center',
            margin: [20, 50, 10, 10],
            width: 50,

        },
        {
            text: "Hello",
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]


        },
        {
            text: "Man",
            style: ['boldBlueText', 'xlSize'],
            margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
        },
        {
            text: "This is krishna ..Jus wanna let you know that you have ",
            margin: [0, 20, 0, 20]

        },
        {
            text: "just" ,
            style: ['boldBlueText', 'lgSize']

        },
        {
            text: "downloaded the pdf document on " + today + ".",
            margin: [0, 20, 0, 20]

        },

    ],
    styles: {
        boldBlueText: {
            color: '#2F418E',
            bold: true
        },
        xlSize: {
            fontSize: 50,
        },
        lgSize: {
            fontSize: 37,
        }
    },
    defaultStyle: {
        alignment: 'center'
    }

};

//red=#AD2430
//blue=#2F418E
//gray=#E7E6E6
//darkgray=#939598
     </script>  
</head>
<script>
    function renderPDF(dd) {
        const createPdf  = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);
        var base64data = null;
        <!-- var participantName = document.getElementById('hdnParticipantName').value; -->
        createPdf.getBase64(function (encodedString) {
            base64data = encodedString;           
            var byteCharacters = atob(base64data);
            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf;base64' });
            //var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);            
            if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(file, 'UserCertificate.pdf');
            } else {
                saveAs(file, 'UserCertificate.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
    pdfMake.fonts = {
        Roboto: {
            normal: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
            bold: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
            italics: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
            bolditalics: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
        },
    }
    renderPDF(usercertificateDD);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Link the script to an event
- Include square brackets

Try the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>

    <script src="../js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function printpdf() {
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [
                    'First paragraph',
                    'Another paragraph'
                ]
            }
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open('test.pdf');
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="make_pdf">Open PDF</button>
<script>document.getElementById('make_pdf').onclick = printpdf ;</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Edit 1: Removed inline onclick event handler*

Comment: Don't define event handlers inline.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Gothdo