# pdfMake - open() and print() functions are not working

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdfmake

I'm trying to learn how to use **pdfMake**. I'm trying to use `open` and `print` to generate or print the information respectively. But, when I click on the button which fires the event, a new tab opens for a second and vanishes. 
The page which opens is displayed in history as `blob:http://localhost:9999/93c1600e-3c64-42fe-8b44-fe6eeb995b5e`

I'm not able to figure out the error. I'm following the official [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake#building-from-sources) of pdfMake.

Please help.

```js
function print(){
  window.event.preventDefault()
  // this is just a simulation of the open event, replacing it with print produces the same result
  var docDefinition = { content: {text:'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake',fontSize:15} };
  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.27/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.27/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/print.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <button onclick="print()">Print Card</button>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see my answer in the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67464831/4748078

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please check that any type of ad blocker in your browser is turned off and try again.

Answer (score 6):

I found solution for printing in same window.

In your .html file put `iframe`

```
<iframe id="printPdf" name="printPdf"></iframe>
```

`iframe` needs style to hide himself for example (I do not know why, but if I define width and height on iframe, printing will not work):

```
#printPdf { position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block;
            padding: 0px;border: 0px;margin: 0px;
            visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; 
}
```

Finally, just call:

```
    if ('safari') {
        pdfMake.createPdf(content).open({}, window.frames['printPdf']);
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.frames['printPdf'].focus();
            window.frames['printPdf'].print();
        }, 2000)
    } else {
        pdfMake.createPdf(content).print({}, window.frames['printPdf']);
    }
```

Tested on Chrome v72, Firefox v65, Edge v18, Safari v12

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer realy help me

Answer (score 0):

for the open() it's not working even without ad blocker so i converted it to base64 then blob then fileURL

```
                   var docDefinition = getRWABELPDF(data);
                   var createPdf = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
                   var base64data = null;

                    createPdf.getBase64(function(encodedString) {
                        base64data = encodedString;
                       console.log(base64data );


                        var byteCharacters = atob(base64data);
                        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
                        }
                        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                        var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf;base64' });
                        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        window.open(fileURL);
```

Answer (score -1):

PDFMake has an [open issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/800) for this problem.

PDFMake creates URLs starting with **blob:** to print/open a generated PDF. The problem is that this pattern of URL is used by many sites to show undesired popups to users. Then EasyList listed this URL pattern and ad blockers started blocking it.

Therefore, as steffanjj suggested, disable your ad blocker and you should be able to print/open the generated PDF. I just wanted to explain in little more detail why this is happening.